# Optimal Combination of vectors to reach a resultant vector.

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, vectors

Suppose I have 8 vectors: $v_1+v_2+...+v_8$.
Assign coefficients to each vector: $S=a_1v_1+a_2v_2+...+a_8v_8$,

I want $S$ to be a resultant vector $\vec{R}$ of my choosing.

The problem is to find the minimal sum of coefficients such that the previous equation holds.

Let $C=\sum_{n=1}^{8}a_n$ and $a_1,a_2,...,a_8\in \mathbb{N\cup0}$

$v_1,v_2,...,v_8:S=R \wedge C=C_{min}$, Where $C_{min}$ is the minimum value of $C$ such that $S=R$.

Note the condition of the coefficients being nonnegative integers.

### **Example**

: Say I have these vectors: $[1,2], [-1,2],[1,-2],[-1,-2],[2,1],[-2,1],[2,-1],[-2,-1]$ (These are actually representative of all the possible knight moves in chess.)

Let $a_1,a_2,...,a_8$ represent the number of each vector when added together (coefficient).
Suppose I want the resultant vector to equal $[3,-3]. $

The optimal 'coefficient set' would be $\{0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0\}$. I.e. $a_1=0,a_2=0,a_3=1,...,a_8=0$. With $C=0+0+1+...+0=2$

---

Is there an **analytical** or at the very least a solution to this with a mathematical formula which can be computed **numerically**. (perhaps with multivariable calculus, linear algebra, etc.)?

**OR if it doesn't seem possible, an efficient computational solution will suffice.**
Or at the very least an efficient method where the number of combinations to trial doesn't grow exponentially, so it can be trialled for large numbers?

If it is a numerical/brute force method, I want it to be reasonable for up to at least $\max(a_i)=100, i\in\{{1,2,...,8}\}$, (you don't need a maximum, but for my attempt, it meant that I could reduce the sample space).

**My computational attempt**: for a set maximum $\max(a_i)$, loop every combination of these and check the result to hence find which reach the target. Then I search for the one with the lowest $C$ value.
As you may expect, the number of combinations grows exponentially. With $max(a_i)>=7$ being unviable.

Comment: You want the coefficients to be integers, but then you write they are in ${\bf N}\cup\{0\}$, so I guess you actually want them to be nonnegative integers. Then the following is guaranteed to work: first, try all the combinations with coefficients summing to one; then all with coefficients summing to two; and so on; stop when you get the resultant vector you want. Well, you didn't say you wanted an *efficient* method.

Comment: This is an integer program.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Ah. I will make an edit to the post. I tried a method like you mentioned but it blows up to too many combinations after about $\max{a}=9$. That is, 9^8 combinations (43 million).

Comment: How many coordinates do your vectors have ?

Comment: @EwanDelanoy 2. It is an (x,y) vector.

Comment: I think more people could help you if you gave one or two random representative examples of numerical values for your vectors.

Comment: I have now added that.

Comment: How representative is that case of the difficulty of the actual problems? Have you looked into integer programming?

Comment: A few hints: have a look at the 'branch and bound' method which is roughly along the lines of your computational attempt. Also, write out the dual problem (in the sense of linear programming) and see if that is easier to solve.

Comment: Note: if you implement a kind of branch and bound method, you can practically limit the search by using lower bounds on the number of remaining moves, at least for the case of the knight move. And of course detect loops, i.e. that you come to a case already considered. I don't think you will get an analytical solution valid for all cases, but yes for the bishop case...

Comment: You have $[1,-2]$ listed twice, and your proposed optimal solution does not seem to yield the desired $[4,4]$.

Comment: Yeah, I just looked at it made a mistake. I changed it now though.

Comment: @Simplex1, does my answer satisfy your needs?  It solves in 0.05 seconds on my laptop.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have suggested, you can solve the problem via integer linear programming (ILP).  Let $v_n^i$ be the $i$th component of vector $v_n$, and let $R^i$ be the $i$th component of $R$. With the decision variables $a_n$ that you defined, the problem is to minimize $\sum_n a_n$ subject to:
\begin{align}
\sum_n v_n^i a_n &= R^i &&\text{for all $i$}\\
a_n &\in \mathbb{N} &&\text{for all $n$}
\end{align}
You can use any ILP solver to find the optimal values, without artificially putting upper bounds on $a_n$.

Here is SAS code to solve your sample instance:

```
proc optmodel;
   set DIMS = 1..2;
   num r {DIMS} = [3,-3];
   set VECTORS = 1..8;
   num v {VECTORS, DIMS} = [1,2,−1,2,1,−2,−1,−2,2,1,−2,1,2,−1,−2,−1];

   var A {VECTORS} >= 0 integer;
   min Z = sum {n in VECTORS} A[n];
   con C {i in DIMS}:
      sum {n in VECTORS} v[n,i] * A[n] = r[i];

   solve;
   print A;
quit;
```

I get an optimal objective value of 2, achieved by $a=(0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0)$.

Comment: This is the obvious answer.